# Calculate factor for real-world time into game time

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ratio

I'm working on a game engine (text-based games) that supports day/night transitions in it. Each world has it's own calendar that manages how many days make up a year, what time zone offsets the world is in from the games universe clock among other things.

I want to make the transitions from day/night configurable, by letting each world define the ratio between a day in the game, to 1 hour in real-world time. An example would be a ratio of 15 minutes in the real-world and represents 1 full day in the game. The reason for this is because the engine has an internal timer that runs when the engine starts up. So I'll always need to convert real-world time into game time anytime I display the time of day in-game. I'm not sure what the math behind this would be - I was looking at `24 game-hours / 15 real-minutes = adjustment factor`.

The intent being that i want to apply this adjustment factor to any real-world time from the engines internal stopwatch, and determine the game-time. That might be `Total Hours elapsed * factor` or `Total Days elapsed * factor`. Am I barking up the wrong tree with this? Math is not my strongest skill set (obviously!) which is hindering me here, and why i'm writing a text-based engine rather than anything with graphics. Is there a formula I could use that would give me a factor I could use for total elapsed days, hours, seconds interchangeably? Or do i need a factor per unit of time measurement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to be careful of is units. In your example with $15$ minutes, convert that to $0.25$ hours so as to calculate how much faster the in-game time is compared to real time:

$$\frac{24\,h}{0.25\,h}=96.$$

So if you know that some time has passed in real time, you have multiply this time by $96$ to get the in-game time. For instance, if half an hour has passed in real time, $0.5\,h\times 96=48$ hours, i.e. two days, has passed in-game.

Comment: Thanks, I think what was throwing off my math was the units now that you mention it. I was trying to apply the ratio I calculated for hours, against elapsed seconds and minutes (one ratio for all units). I'll either create a ratio per unit, or handle all my math at the seconds unit, with a single ratio. Much appreciated!

Comment: @JohnathonSullinger Yes, units can be tricky! However, the ratio doesn't change when changing units, as long as both units are the same. E.g., $\frac{24\,h}{0.25\,h}=\frac{1440\,m}{15\,m}=96,$ where $m$ is minutes. Good luck with your game!

Comment: Oh that's good to know - I didn't even realize the ratio would be the same woo! That massively simplifies things for me, thanks!

Comment: @JohnathonSullinger No problem! Think of it as "time moves $96$ times faster in-game" - that statement doesn't mention anything about units.